# How to delete a file while it is attached to a stream

Tags: c#, io, stream, udp, delete-file

I have developed a UDP Client console application to retrieve packet data and write them into text files. I have been using a stream to write data into text files. As the text files are being written throughout the day, it is not possible to dispose the stream. The files are generated in daily basis and I need to delete the text files written on previous days. But it is not possible to delete the files; there is an error message saying that the file has been used by another process. Although the previous day files are not being actually written at the moment, still they seem to be attached to the stream. As I'm unable to dispose or close the stream, is there a possible way to delete those old text files attached to the particular process? Thank you.

Comment: What is stopping you from disposing the stream when you've finished writing to them for that day?

Comment: @Baldrick - It is related to the project's overall functionality. I'm writing encrypted data in text files and decrypting them back by a separate windows forms application. Both encryption and decryption process use the same encryption key and in order to keep the process consistent, I have to remain the same stream. As you have suggested I tried to dispose the stream at the end of the day, but it affected the decryption process by resulting corrupted (decrypted) data. Thank you.

Comment: It seems like you have a design issue you're trying to workaround by doing things in an inadvisable way. I'd strongly suggest redesigning your encryption mechanism so you are able to clean up your file streams properly. If a file is locked in this way, windows won't let you delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are not disposing your stream properly. They are still 'alive' in memory. You should figure out what keeps your streams from being garbage collected. You could do this, for example, by keeping a reference to all your streams in a global property (or better, a manager) along with a `DateTime` timestamp at which it was created. That way, by checking the timestamp, you can identify which streams can be closed. Make sure you both **close** and **dispose** your streams.

Note that streams are costly resources and usage should be kept to a minimum.

Comment: Wicher Visser and Baldrick - Thank you for your support. I had to change my design of using threads and I was able to dispose the streams safely without affecting the decryption process.